# How to execute truffle commands through an API or a code?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, polygon, smartcontracts, nft

The eventual thing that I want to achieve is to migrate/deploy a smart contract using truffle through an API call. I would prefer to do it in NodeJs.

This question is related to deployment of smart contracts on Ethereum and Polygon network. I am able to deploy using command line interface `truffle` commands. For example `truffle migrate --network matic`. How do I run these commands through code?
Do I need to use [chile_proces.exec](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) function to execute the truffle commands? Or is there a different way that devs are already doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a script and use docker file to run all these commands or a simple shell script file which fulfils all these details.